# Intercepting Key Inputs Natively in C#

Tags: c#, .net, macros, hook, native

I have an API built in C# that uses native key hooks to execute macros at runtime, but these macros need to be executed in another program (hence the native hooks). The macros work, but I was wondering if there is any way that I could intercept these inputs in my application so that the key press doesn’t end up reaching the external program. The closest thing I can think of would be how AutoHotKey handles its inputs.

Comment: do you want your c# app to interact with external applications ?

Comment: @Clint Yes. I’m using the built-in .NET functionality for sending keyboard and mouse input.

Comment: right, are you looking for alternate ways of interacting with expternal apps besides keyboard strokes and mouse inputs ?

Comment: No, those are the only two methods I've got a need for.

Comment: ok and what is that you wish to accomplish, ?

Comment: I want to intercept the hotkeys that I use to trigger my macros so that the hotkeys themselves aren’t sent to the external application. Like if I hit F to trigger a macro, I don’t want F to get sent to the program as well, but rather be captured by my program to execute the macro.